# vim: switch to unlisted buffer dir

Tags: vim, netrw

In netrw version 134 I could use the following work pattern:

```
open dir x
select file a
:b#     back to dir x
select file b
:b#     back to dir x
select file c
... etc ...
```

But in netw version 149 this doesn't work.

The `b#` refuses to redisplay the directory buffer, which is unlisted.

How can I convince `b#` to display the unlisted directory buffer?

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: What is vim 134 and vim 149? Do you mean vim patch numbers or do you mean netrw version numbers (I believe you mean netrw version numbers). Netrw is one of the default plugins in vim. I can reproduce the behavior. I do not know if this was intended or not. You should email the developer as he is actively maintaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got used to a what looks a lot like a bug (there are many in netrw) or at least an oversight.

The correct way to go back to the netrw window is:

```
:Rex
```

Answer (score 0):

Try netrw v153q: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

I was unable to duplicate this problem with the latest version of netrw.